# REST API not enabled for org - whitelisted managed package

Tags: rest-api, managed-package, group-edition

We have a managed package in the AppExchange that leverages the SF REST API for data access outside of our users' orgs. Within our managed package is a RestResource class that verifies the user's license for our tool. We seem to be running into an issue with a Group Edition user that attempts to use our tool and gets the message 'The REST API is not enabled for this organization' when attempting to authenticate using our managed package's Rest Resource class.

We sent a request to Salesforce for our managed package to be whitelisted for API access by GE and PE orgs a few months ago and were approved. Why might this still be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "[API Access in Group and Professional Editions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_api_access.htm)" page, it seems that you've followed the correct procedure for whitelisting your app and enabling access to the `@RestResource` class in your package.

I think the only way for you to resolve this problem is to log a case with Salesforce Support to troubleshoot the error. I would use the **highest Severity Level** possible, since as far as I can tell there is no workaround you can reasonably implement.

While the case is being processed, perhaps you can spin up a Group Edition test org using Environment Hub, and try installing and using your package in that org. This exercise would simply be an additional data point to help you expedite your case by providing information on whether the problem is likely with your package or with your customer's specific GE org.

Comment: Thanks Marty, I actually opened up a case with SF to no avail, as they don't offer support to non-premier partners it seems. I will try to escalate and see what happens.